# How to declare the Char array of char variables already declared in class?

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, pointers, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//char* b[6] = new char[6];

char a[6] = {'b','c','d','e','f','g'};
char c[6] = {'a','b','d','d','f','g'};

int main()
{
    char d[][6]={*a,*c};



    for (int x = 0 ; x < 1; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y<6; y++)
        {
            char test = d[x][y];
            cout << test <<"\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is C++ code. I am trying to create a class where it stores the char array. Then there is another char array of array storing already declared char variables. It compiles fine but it doesn't work out to as it should. It doesn't get me the right value that it should when the program tries to print the value

Answer (score 2):

May be you meant array of pointers:

```
char *d[]={a,c};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef std::vector<char>          VectorChar;
typedef std::vector< VectorChar* > VectorVectorChar;

struct V
{
  V() : _v{ '0', '1', '2' } {}

  VectorChar _v;
};

int main(void)
{
    V arrV[5];

    VectorVectorChar vvc;
    for ( auto& v : arrV )
       vvc.push_back( &v._v );

    // print them
    for ( auto pV : vvc )
    {
      for ( auto c : *pV )
          cout << c << ' ';
      cout << '\n;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i understood from the question that, you want to create class to store char array, which already initialized.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

    char a[6] = {'b','c','d','e','f','g'};  // Initialized character array. MAX 6

    // This class will hold char array
    class Test {    
    public:
        void setName(char *name);
        const char* getName();
    private:
        char m_name[6]; // MAX 6 ( since you already initialized(MAX 6), So no need dynamic memory allocation. )
    };

    void Test::setName(char *name) {
        strcpy(m_name, name); // Copy, already initialized array
    }

    const char* Test::getName() {
        return m_name;
    }

   int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    {
        Test foobar;       
        foobar.setName( a );  // set the pointer which point to starting of the initialized array.
        cout << foobar.getName();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[6] = {'b','c','d','e','f','\0'};
char c[6] = {'a','b','d','d','f','\0'};
char* d[]= {a,c};

for (int x = 0 ; x < 2; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
    {
        char test = d[x][y];
        cout << test << "\n";
    }
}

return 0;
```

Comment: note that `d`'s entries point at `a` and `c` in this case; it does not make a copy of them